# How can I work out what is filtering a port in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, ssh, iptables

I recently did a `yum update` and `reboot`, and now I can't SSH into my machine.  I use a non-standard SSH port (let's say 444) and when I run `nmap <MY-IP> -p444 --reason` I get `444/tcp filtered unknown host-prohibited`.  If I run `-p22` instead I get `22/tcp closed ssh`.

I've booted into the rescue mode and mounted my disk and I'm unclear where iptables rules are stored.  I think they should be in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`, but that file doesn't exist.  I got this server a while ago for an experiment and it is possible that I never set any firewall rules up.  But if that's the case then what's filtering port 444?  Could it be something other than iptables - if so how do I find it?

Thank you!

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-using_firewalls

Comment: Can you be more specific...!

Comment: First set the ssh port back to 22 and reboot your system. Then spend a few minutes learning about firewalld.

Comment: Thanks.  I've already done this, then added the rule for 444 and switched ssh back over, etc.  Why would it have changed with a yum update though, it was working perfectly beforehand?

Answer (score 0):

You are using non-standard port for SSH. SELinux must have relabeled the file contexts after system reboot.

To temporarily disable SELinux

```
$ sudo setenforce 0
```

If you decide to keep using non-standard port for SSH while SELinux enabled, use the semanage command:

```
$ sudo semanage port -a -t ssh_port_t -p tcp 4444
```

Then allow add the port to firewall exceptions:

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=4444/tcp --permanent
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

To disable SELinux permanently, follow this [guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/security-enhanced_linux/sect-security-enhanced_linux-enabling_and_disabling_selinux-disabling_selinux)

Comment: SELinux is already disabled, so it wasn't that.